# How to remove unwanted tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<para>
    <p>
        This is text
    </p>
    <p/>
    <p/>
    <p>
        This Is text
    </p>
</para>
```

The Output must be :

```
<para>
<p>
This is text
</p>
<p>
This Is text
</p>
</para>
```

I want to remove this "`<p/>`" tag, how can i do that using xslt?

Comment: You should read up on the basic approach for writing XSLT which copies the input through to the output with some transformations. In this case, you'll want a template which matches an empty `p` element and does nothing (meaning nothing will be output, meaning it will be "removed").

Comment: You have already asked this question twice.

Comment: I ask it in different thread michael

Answer (score 1):

```
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/><!--Remove all the attributes-->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" />
```

problem solve after reading some of my books and understanding  what  @torazaburo instruction..